# Bootstrap accordion jQuery script doesnt work on Apache server

Tags: jquery, apache, bootstrap-4

> jQuery

```
$('.accordions').each(function(){

        // Set First Accordion As Active
        $(this).find('.accordion-content').hide();
        if(!$(this).hasClass('toggles')){
            $(this).find('.accordion:first-child').addClass('accordion-active');
            $(this).find('.accordion:first-child .accordion-content').show();
        }

        // Set Accordion Events
        $(this).find('.accordion-header').click(function(){

            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('accordion-active')){

                // Close other accordions
                if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('toggles')){
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.accordion-active').removeClass('accordion-active').find('.accordion-content').slideUp(300);
                }

                // Open Accordion
                $(this).parent().addClass('accordion-active');
                $(this).parent().find('.accordion-content').slideDown(300);

            }else{

                // Close Accordion
                $(this).parent().removeClass('accordion-active');
                $(this).parent().find('.accordion-content').slideUp(300);

            }

        });

    });
```

> HTML

```
<ul class="accordions">
                        <!-- Accordion -->
                        <li class="accordion">
                            <div class="accordion-header">
                                <div class="accordion-icon"></div>
                                <h6>Section 1</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-content" style="display: none;">
                                <p>text</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- /Accordion -->
```

Hi,
The following jQuery code works fine when runed locally. When I try runing it on a local Apache server, the click event doesnt register. I am using jQuery 1.11 (not running it on a CDN). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The server makes no difference, everything here runs in the browser.  When you debug, how *specifically* is this failing?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Are any resources failing to load in the browser's network debugging tab?  When you debug in your browser, are any elements found when attaching the click handler?  What specifically happens when debugging?

Comment: @David There are no errors on the console. The only difference is when I console.log ($(this).find('.accordion-header')); it doesnt output anything when I load it on the server.

Comment: Then there are no elements to attach click handlers to at that time.  *Should* there be?  Are elements being loaded dynamically in any way?  You need to expand on the details of the example, because the code shown works.  (As you've already seen when running it locally.)